# detect change through traversal

Tags: jquery, traversal

I want to detect change in a dropdown box through traversal.

Something along the lines of

> $('#id').next().next().onChange(function(){.....})
>   or
>      $('#id').next().next().blur(function(){.....})

But maybe Im barking up the wrong tree here.
I have 3 `select` boxes all related (City, Region, Country)
I want to apply the *obvious* values to the `region` and `country` box if the value in `city` has no other relations

Im using `SELECT2` at the moment and it creates its own DIV SELECT from you SELECT BOX.

The only unique item from this is a ID that is created 3 DOM items up from where the value is kept.

so hence. If I can detect change through traversal it should work. But how can I do that?

Here is a example

```
<div class="select2-container storeEditBox_split csSelect" id="s2id_region">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="select2-choice" tabindex="-1">
    <span class="select2-chosen" id="select2-chosen-3">Buckinghamshire</span>
    <abbr class="select2-search-choice-close"></abbr>
    <span class="select2-arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span>
  </a>
  <label for="s2id_autogen3" class="select2-offscreen"></label>
  <input class="select2-focusser select2-offscreen" type="text" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" aria-labelledby="select2-chosen-3" id="s2id_autogen3">
</div>
```

**s2id_region** on the first line being the only reliable `id` in the snippet here.
**Buckinghamshire** on line 3 the value that was selected here.

**PS**

Like Joe mentioned in the comments. There is a lot of clutter in the code area, but THIS is what SELECT2 has created automatically. Im sorry if it confuses the matter.

**The main point here is:** Is it possible to detect change on a DOM element through traversal?

**CLEAND-UP VERSION**

```
<div id="s2id_region">
  <a>
    <span>Buckinghamshire</span>
    <abbr></abbr>
    <span><b></b></span>
  </a>
  <label></label>
  <input type="text"role="button">
</div>
```

Comment: Rather than telling us how you're trying to do it and asking why it doesn't work, a clear explanation of WHAT you want (with clean, uncluttered markup) is a better starting point. Still say "I've tried this..." but the question part should be "how do I solve this problem", not "why doesn't this solution work?"

Comment: Joe, If tried that in the past and got a lot of downvotes. So now Im trying to tell you what I have planned, what I have tried and what I expect the solution to look like. But like I said, *'Maybe Im barking up the wrong tree'*. Yes, If im completely on the wrong track here, please be so kind as to guide me in the right direction.

Comment: I'm just struggling to understand exactly what you're trying to do. I know you have 3 selects (City, Region, Country), but I don't know which order you're trying to do things in (should Re/Co autofill based on known Cities, or should Re/Ci allow you to narrow down from a list of Countries?). Then your HTML snippet is cluttered with classes, tabindex, aria- attributes etc when you say the only reliable thing is the line-1 ID - just remove the irrelevant stuff :-)